# KnockoutJs Binding Variable Numbers of Controls

Tags: javascript, knockout.js

In KnockoutJs, I have a list of controls that I want to bind to the page as in:

```
{
  ...
  "FirstName": "Fred",
  "LastName": "Jones",
  "Controls": [
    {
      "Name": "ImageSrc"
      "CurrentValue": "/FredJonesPicture.jpg",
      ...etc...
    },
    {
      "Name": "ImageCaption",
      "CurrentValue": "Quarterback Fred Jones",
      ...etc...
    },
    {
      "Name": "HomeTeamScore",
      "CurrentValue": "7",
      ...etc...
    }
   ]
   etc...
}
```

with a templates (`*ImageSrc*` etc are placeholders)  like :

```
<script type="text/html" id="template1">
    <div class="mainContent" data-bind="with: Model" >
        <h3 data-bind="text: *ImageCaption*"></h3>
        <img data-bind="attr:{ src: *ImageSrc* }" class="activeImage" />
        <div data-bind="text: *HomeTeamScore*"></div>
    </div>
</script>  

<script type="text/html" id="template2">
    <div class="mainContent" data-bind="with: Model" >
        <h3 data-bind="text: *Quote*"></h3>
        <img data-bind="attr:{ src: *ImageSrc* }" />
        <h3 data-bind="text: *Song*"></h3>
        <img data-bind="attr:{ src: *Icon* }" style="floatleft"  />
        <div data-bind="text: *Band*"></div>
    </div>
</script>
```

etc...

The problem is that there can be a multiple possible templates with a variable number of controls (possibly in the hundreds) for each one. There will be only one template per page.

What is the simplest, most efficient syntax to bind to the page? A function that you pass variables to, a custombinding, or is there some sort of built-in binding technique that I am missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is one answer that I came up with that works but does not seem very efficient:

```
self.GetControlValue = function (name)
{
    if (self.Controls().length > 0)
    { 
        var control = ko.utils.arrayFirst(self.Controls(), function (c) 
        {
            return c.Name() === name;
        });

        var value = (control) ? control.CurrentValue() : "";
     }
    return value || "";
};
```

Binding:

```
<img data-bind="attr:{ src: GetControlValue('ActiveImageSrc') }" />
```

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you have a strangely-formed dictionary. If I understand your example code, you want to bind the `CurrentValue` associated with a `Name`. If your control structure were like

```
Controls: {
    ImageSrc: {
        CurrentValue: "/FredJonesPicture.jpg",
        ...
    },
    ...
}
```

then your binding would be like

```
    <img data-bind="attr:{ src: Controls.ImgSrc.CurrentValue }" class="activeImage" />
```

You could write a `computed` to transform your Controls, if the array structure is not up to you.

Comment: Thanks, but that does not really the issue of binding to a flattened list of controls to a page.

Comment: I think it does, but maybe I don't understand what you're trying to do. Do you really intend to have asterisks in your template, making it nonstandard? Can you be more clear about what your inputs and expected outputs are?

Comment: I see where you are coming from with the structure, but I would have to somehow convert Controls (an array of Control) to a Controls (with named properties). I'm not sure how to do that in json.net without having to have control sub-types but it may bear research on my part. Not sure I would want to do a transform like that in a Computed